# Sort List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> in primary and secondary way?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, comparator

Okay. So I have an ArrayList of Map<String, Integer>:

```
  Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> wordSet = map.entrySet();
  List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> wordList = new ArrayList<>(wordSet);
        
  wordList.sort((w1, w2) -> w2.getValue().compareTo(w1.getValue()));
```

As you can see here this sort will only sort based on the Value in the Map<K,V>. I wanna modify the lambda-expression so it PRIMARILY checks for the greatest value, and SECONDARY checks the alphabetical order. However, I'm not sure how to create a lambda-expression in this way that has a Primary and Secondary way.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Comparator utility methods instead. Replace your current with:

```java
wordList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
```

This utility method makes a comparator that does what your comparator does: map both entries by calling getValue, then compare that object.

All comparators have a `.thenComparing` method:

```java
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> secondOrder = Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey());

wordList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue).thenComparing(secondOrder));
```

This will compare on value, and if those are equal, then compare on key. You can make that compare on whatever you please.

Comment: This worked. Is you solution better?

Comment: wordList.sort((w1, w2) -> {
            int x = w2.getValue().compareTo(w1.getValue());
            if(x == 0) {
                return w1.getKey().compareTo(w2.getKey());
            }
            return x;
        });

Comment: They both 'work', you tell me which one you find more readable and easier to modify if someone asks you to change it. I think `Comparator.comparing(...).thenComparing(...)` is whole ballparks more readable and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to sort the map entries by value () in descending order and *then* by keys (words) in alphabetical order.

`Map.Entry` has its own static comparator methods [Map.Entry::comparingByValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue-java.util.Comparator-) and [Map.Entry::comparingByKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey--) which can be joined using `Comparator::thenComparing`:

```java
wordList.sort(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()));
```

Also, [`Comparator::reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) may be used instead of `Comparator::reverseOrder`:

```java
wordList.sort(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()
        .reversed()
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
);
```